# Google Sheets API CopyPasteRequest has no effect

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-api

I am simply trying to copy a range of cells from the first sheet in my spreadsheet to the second.  This code runs without error, but nothing happens on the actual sheet.

What am I missing below?

```
 var spreadSheet = service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId).Execute();
 int? sourceSheetId = spreadSheet.Sheets[0].Properties.SheetId;
 int? targetSheetId = spreadSheet.Sheets[1].Properties.SheetId;

 // Copy in the current data from the "Training Data" tab
 CopyPasteRequest copyReq = new CopyPasteRequest()
 {
     Source = new GridRange() {  SheetId = sourceSheetId, StartColumnIndex = 0, 
         StartRowIndex = 1, EndColumnIndex = 0, EndRowIndex = 3000 },
     Destination = new GridRange() { SheetId = targetSheetId, 
         StartColumnIndex = 0, StartRowIndex = 1, EndColumnIndex = 0, EndRowIndex = 3000 },
     PasteType = "PASTE_VALUES",
     PasteOrientation = "NORMAL"
 };

 var copyResource = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest() { Requests = new List<Request>() };
 var reqCopy = new Request() { CopyPaste = copyReq };
 copyResource.Requests.Add(reqCopy);

 var result = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(copyResource, spreadsheetId).Execute();
 // no errors, and result object is populated -- but nothing appears in the target sheet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you are trying to copy Column A of a source sheet to Column A of the destination sheet.

The reason why there is no effect in your request is because your `EndColumnIndex` in the [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#gridrange) is incorrect, `EndColumnIndex` and `EndRowIndex` are excluded in the range to be copied.

> **endRowIndex**
>
> The end row (exclusive) of the range, or not set if unbounded.
>
> **endColumnIndex**
>
> The end column (exclusive) of the range, or not set if unbounded.

---

### Example:

I want to copy `Sheet1!A1:A10` to `Sheet2!A1:A10`

[image]

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "copyPaste": {
        "source": {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1,
          "endRowIndex": 10
        },
        "destination": {
          "sheetId": 133812xxxx,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1,
          "endRowIndex": 10
        },
        "pasteOrientation": "NORMAL",
        "pasteType": "PASTE_NORMAL"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- sheet index is zero-based
- `endColumnIndex` is set to 1 (Column B excluded)
- `endRowIndex` is set to 10 (Row 11 excluded)

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, you interpreted my question correctly and taught me what I needed to know.  The "end-column" and "end-row" really mean "the first column or row you *don't* want included."  I see how the documentation says "excluded" -- and I did not interpret it as they meant it.

Comment: Glad that I could help